# Is it overloading or overriding?

Tags: java, overloading, overriding

I have a code and I am not able to get why the output will be "Radial Tire with long".Can somebody help me to understand this code?

```
class Tyre {
    public void front() throws RuntimeException {
        System.out.println("Tire");
    }

    public void front(long a) {
        System.out.println("Radial Tire with long");
    }
}

class TestSolution extends Tyre {
    public void front() {
        System.out.println("Radial Tire");
    }
    public void front(int a) throws RuntimeException {
        System.out.println("Radial Tire with int");
    }


public static void main(String... args) {
        Tyre t = new TestSolution();
        int a = 10;
        t.front(a);

}

}
```

Comment: No overriding here.

Comment: If you can add `@Override` to the method without it being a compiler error, you are overriding the method. Note that it is a good idea to add that annotation as a matter of course.

Comment: Thats not overriding :)

Answer (score 4):

`front` is not *overridden* in `TestSolution`, it is *overloaded*.

You can regard an *overloaded* function as a completely different function, like one with a different name.

So `t.front(a)` will call the one in `Tyre`, with an `a` implicitly converted to `long`.

Comment: Thanks , but one thing TestSolution extends Tyre as well then won't it be a case of overriding too?

Comment: No. An *overridden* function has to have the same *signature*. That means that the function name and parameter types have to match exactly. Some flexibility is allowable for the return type, but that's beyond the question scope here.

Answer (score 1):

So if we go with definitions

Overloading means methods with same name but with different number or order of parameters.

Overriding means method with same name with same number of parameters along with rules mentioned [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm)

So in your case `front` method is overloaded in both the classes `Tyre` and `TestSolution`

method `front()` from `Tyre` class is overridden in class `TestSolution`.

no overriding in case of method `front(long a)` and `front(int a)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no overriding taking place in your `main`.

`t`'s static (compile-time) type is `Tyre`, so, since method overload resolution is determined by the compile-time type of the instance, the only `front` methods available for the compiler to choose from are those declared in the base class `Tyre` :

```
public void front()
public void front(long a)
```

Only the latter (`public void front(long a)`) matches the arguments of the call `t.front(a)`, and that method is not overridden by the sub-class. Therefore `Radial Tire with long` is displayed.

Calling `((TestSolution)t).front(a);` would invoke the sub-class's method - `public void front(int a)`.

Comment: Thanks Eran, but TestSolution does contain a overridden front(int a), then why does it go for the one defined in super class?

Comment: @Arzoo `void front(int a)` doesn't override any method in the base class, since the base class has no method with such signature. Therefore  `void front(int a)` is not overridden. If you had a `void front(int a)` method in the base class, the `void front(int a)` method in TestSolution would have been executed, due to overriding.

Comment: Okay, you are right i missed that minute details, Thanks Eran :-)

Answer (score 0):

General rule: if I have a variable of one class I can access only methods and components defined in that class.

The only particular case is:

1. you have a component or method both in the super class and in the subclass (overriding)
2. you have a variable of the super class and an object of the subclass (your case)

In these cases you can follow the following rule:

1. for the components the type of the variable decides which to use
2. for the methods the type of the object does (late binding)

In your case as stated before the method is not overridden so you can't apply the last rule.

Answer (score 0):

Lets understand the difference between [overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and [overriding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Overloading:

> The Java programming language supports overloading methods, and Java can distinguish between methods with different method signatures. This means that methods within a class can have the same name if they have different parameter lists

Overriding:

> An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters) and return type as an instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method.

`Tyre` declared `front()` method with `long` as parameter.

`TyreSolution` declared `front()` method with `int` as parameter.

Since the method signature is different,  `TyreSolution` overloads `Tyre`'s  `front()` method

If you change signature of `front()` in `TyreSolution` to accept `long` value as input parameter instead of `int`, then `TyreSolution` overrides `Tyre's` `front()` method.

e.g. `TestSolution` class definition of `front()` method

```
public void front(long a) throws RuntimeException {
    System.out.println("Radial Tire with long in TestSolution");
}
```

output:

```
Radial Tire with long in TestSolution
```