# OVERLOADING OR OVERRIDING?

Tags: java

```
class P
    {
        public void m1(int i,float f)
            {
            System.out.println("int-float");
            }
    }
class C extends P
    {
        public void m1(float f,int i)
            {
            System.out.println("float-int");
            }
    }
class Test
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
            {
            P p=new P();
            p.m1(10,10.5f);
            C c=new C();
            c.m1(10.5f,10);
            P p1=new C();
            p1.m1(10,10);
            }   
    }
```

I am unable to understand the concep of this program?

Comment: overloading....

Comment: I am unable to understand your question...

Comment: that's overloading. Overriding happens only if the method signature of the parent and subclass matches

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/mobile-software-development/topic/563737

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it overloading or overriding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243846/is-it-overloading-or-overriding)

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?